# how to get Facebook taggable friends Email Ids

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Javascript sdk to get logged in user contacts {Name ,Email}
according to recent update in user_friends we can only get friends of the users who also uses the same app. so i am trying to get user taggable friends in taggable friends we can get user friends id and name but not friends Email. is there any posibility to get taggable friends Email Id from their Id

Comment: You of course _don’t_ get email addresses for those friends – `taggable_friends` is for tagging friends only; don’t try to abuse it for any other purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. All `friends_*` permissions have been removed. Taggable friends nodes do not contain the email address.

> All friends_* permissions have been removed.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-taggable-friend/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/taggable_friends/

Comment: i know taggable friends don't contain Email address, node consists their fb id , from that is there any possibility to get the email. id->Email address

Comment: No, it's not possible. That would be a breach of security.

Comment: Thanks , Is there any possibility to get user friends Email id's

Comment: Only if those friends start using your app themselves, and grant you the `email` permission.